How to execute a future immediately
Say I have a future defined as follows
val fut = Future {
  println("Doing some work")
  Thread.sleep(5000)
  println("Work done")
}

I am accessing this future later in time but would like to have it execute on startup rather than when I reference fut
I read somewhere that it can be executed immediately by doing:
scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global.execute(fut)

However this will not compile as execute only takes a Runnable.
Is there a way I can execute this future immediately in a different thread?

Are you looking for Await.result(fut, timeout)? https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking-outside-the-future

@DmytroMitin I think OP is looking for non eager futures.

Futures are executed immediately, at least in the way you're using them right now. fut is started right after instantiation. Can you explain how is that not the behaviour you want?

Scala Futures created using Future.apply are eagerly executed.
For non-eager execution, you will have to define your own class to indirectly create Future using Promise.
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

class NonEagerFuture[A](computation: => A) extends Runnable {
  private val promise = Promise[A]

  override def run(): Unit = {
    Try(computation) match {
      case Success(result)    => promise.success(result)
      case Failure(exception) => promise.failure(exception)
    }
  }

  def isFutureCompleted(): Boolean =
    promise.isCompleted

  def getResult(): A =
    if (!promise.isCompleted) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Future is not completed yet")
    } else {
      promise.future.value.get.get
    }

  def getScalaFuture(): Future[A] =
    promise.future

}

It can be used as following,
println("creating the future")

val nonEagerFuture = new NonEagerFuture({
  println("Doing some work")
  Thread.sleep(5000)
  println("Work done")
  println("returning 5 as result")
  5
})

println("running for the future")
scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global.execute(nonEagerFuture)

// can also get the internal scala future and use it
// this scala future will not have the eager problem 
println("get the scala future") 
val scalaFuture = nonEagerFuture.getScalaFuture()
println("printing scalaFuture" + scalaFuture)

// or block for completion using isFutureCompleted
println("checking for the future")
while (!nonEagerFuture.isFutureCompleted()) {
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  println("Checking completed: " + nonEagerFuture.isFutureCompleted())
}

println("getting result for the future")
println("Result: " + nonEagerFuture.getResult())


So to answer my original question - there is no need to explicitly execute using the ec as a Future is always eagerly executed from within the apply() method
